# selecting to a list which is already declared

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

I have below piece of code which is selecting from a list and inside selection it instantiates other list and copy natched data into it.

```
var rep = Histories.Select(rec => new ReportRecord()
                            {
                                Name = rec.ProductName,
                                Total = rec.AdvanceTotal,
                                BidTotal = rec.LiveTotal

                            });
```

I need to modify this code (which I cant because of limited Lambda skills) so that `var rep` should be instantiated before select. Something like:

```
 var rep = new ReportRecord();
 Histories.Select(c => rep.ProductName=c.Name,
 rep.Total=c.AdvanceTotal,
 rep.BidTotal=rec.LiveTotal);
```

Can you please help me with correct syntex ?

I really appriciate your help and guidance.

Thanks

Comment: @Toubi, your question makes no sense to me.  Please elaborate on what specific problem you are actually trying to solve, rather than requesting a particular language idiom that may or may not be applicable to your problem.

Comment: the type for `rep` is diffrent in your two examples, in the first example it is `IEnumerable<ReportRecord>` in the 2nd example it is just `ReportRecord`, you need to do like Kirk says and explain more on *what you are trying to do*, not ask *how to do the solution you thought might work to do what you are trying to do*. This is known as [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather un-clear. If you clarify it a bit, then we will be able to answer your question better.

However what I think you are wanting is a single instance of `ReportRecord` populated with the data from `Histories`.

```
var rep = Histories.Select(rec => new ReportRecord()
                            {
                                ProductName = rec.Name,
                                Total = rec.AdvanceTotal,
                                BidTotal = rec.LiveTotal

                            }).First();
```

This will get the first record from `Histories`, and then populate a new `ReportRecord` with that rows values.

`var` is a placeholder type. It can be anything. The compiler works out what it should be.
However I personally find it clearer if you specify the type if you know what it is.
Like this:

```
ReportRecord rep = Histories.Select(rec => new ReportRecord()
                            {
                                ProductName = rec.Name,
                                Total = rec.AdvanceTotal,
                                BidTotal = rec.LiveTotal

                            }).First();
```

The solution I have given will give you the first row from `Histories` if you want the last then you would replace `.First();` with `.Last();`

**Further info:**

In your original code sample you get an `IEnumerable<ReportRecord>` (or perhaps an IQuerable)  That is a collection of ReportRecords, which does not get populated until you try and extract a value from it. For example by calling First(), ToList(), Sum().

There are also other operation you can perform like filtering  which will not run until down the list using .Where() which wont actually be called until you call First() or something like that e.g.,

```
//Get the first record from Histories where the product name is "Magic beans" and populate a new ReportRecord with those values
ReportRecord rep = Histories.Select(rec => new ReportRecord()
                            {
                                ProductName = rec.Name,
                                Total = rec.AdvanceTotal,
                                BidTotal = rec.LiveTotal

                            }).Where(w => w.Name == "magic beans")
                              .First();
```

Here is some examples of the other LINQ extension methods http://www.nilzorblog.com/2013/05/101-linq-samples-lambda-style.html

Answer (score 0):

The `Select()` method you are calling is probably going to return an `IEnumerable<ReportRecord>` and not a single value.  In your workaround you are using a single value.  This might be confusing you.